# Recover a forgotten password by sending email and code in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm trying to do a VB.NET system to recover a forgotten password. I managed to send an email with a verification code which is then entered into the textbox and lets the user go to the next step if it is correct. I would need it to keep according to the email that was entered to send the code and change the password based on it.

```vb
Private Sub btnSend_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSend.Click
    Dim from, pass, messageBody As String
    Dim rand As Random = New Random()
    randomCode = (rand.Next(999999)).ToString()
    Dim message As MailMessage = New MailMessage()
    toUser = txtEmail.Text
    from = "email"
    pass = "password"
    messageBody = "Your reset code is " + randomCode
    message.To.Add(toUser)
    message.From = New MailAddress(from)
    message.Body = messageBody
    message.Subject = "Password resseting code"
    Dim smtp As SmtpClient = New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com")
    smtp.EnableSsl = True
    smtp.Port = 587
    smtp.DeliveryMethod = smtp.DeliveryMethod.Network
    smtp.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(from, pass)
    Try
        smtp.Send(message)
        MessageBox.Show("Please check your email and enter the code in the enter code textbox")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try 
End Sub
```

So I have another form where the user can change the password.

```vb
Private Sub btnChange_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnChange.Click
    ds = New DataSet
    adapter = New MySqlDataAdapter("update users(password) VALUES('" & txtConfirmPassword.Text & "')", conn)
    MessageBox.Show("Password resetted successfully")
End Sub
```

So how do I update the password in MySQL based on the email entered in the previous form? What's the code for that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute an `UPDATE` statement to modify a single record without retrieving the record into a `DataTable` first then don't use a data adapter. Create a `MySqlCommand`, configure it appropriately and then call `ExecuteNonQuery`.

To learn what ADO.NET types and members to use in what situations, you might like to check out my examples [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?469872). The code is written using `SqlClient` for SQL Server but the same principles apply no matter what database or provider you're using.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm in this new one and I still don't understand how I can follow up on the previously entered e-mail so that I can change my password? The whole system of sending email and code works for me, but I still can't come up with a new password, I'm sorry, I really don't understand much.

Comment: Questions on SO need to be specific. It seems like you are hoping to get help on multiple steps of the process, which would require you to post multiple specific questions. You've asked how to save a new password to the database and I've told you. If you have a question about an earlier step in the process then you need to ask that separately and provide information specific to that.

Comment: I'll try to write it again, I'm not very familiar with MySQL and therefore I can't understand it. I need to send an email that is registered with some username and password in the database. An email will arrive with a verification code, which will be entered into the textbox and it will be verified that the code is valid. Subsequently, if it goes well, it will switch to another form where the password will be changed based on the previously entered email.

Comment: I've already done it, thank you for your help. I added a definition to the previous form based on it, then I wrote a command.